# Rails Skipping Migrations from Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

We are performing a fresh db create and migrate in our build pipeline and rails is skipping all migrations that come from gem. We can see this by doing a check on migration status after.

- docker-compose up -d
- sleep 5
- docker-compose run -e "RAILS_ENV=test" web rake db:create db:migrate
- docker-compose run -e "RAILS_ENV=test" web rake db:migrate:status
- docker-compose run -e "RAILS_ENV=test" web rspec --format RspecJunitFormatter --out rspec.xml
- docker-compose down

[image]

Comment: Which gem contains the migrations?

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/zuora_connect

Comment: This only appears to be effecting rails 5 apps, not rails 4.

Comment: I'm curious as to what `rake db:create` outputs. Are you starting from a clean state, or does it say `already exists`?

Answer (score 0):

Run

`docker-compose run -e "RAILS_ENV=test" web rake db:create db:schema:load`

instead of

`docker-compose run -e "RAILS_ENV=test" web rake db:create db:migrate`

Comment: `db:schema:load` creates your database schema from the `db/schema.rb` file. This is fine to do in the test environment, but, for the love of god, **DO NOT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION**.

Comment: Except when setting up the production environment ;) Also might need to be substituted with `db:structure:load`, when using `structure.sql` instead of `schema.rb`. Unfortunately that doesn't explain why it would work with Rails 4 but not Rails 5.

Comment: Best not to ever run that command in production, especially if you are automating deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your `db/migrate` directory contains those migrations: usually one needs to  manually copy over migrations from ones engines into the host application. The [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) recommends

> bin/rails railties:install:migrations

To avoid this step, but only possible if you have influence over the code of your engine, I like to do something along the lines of:

```
# Skips copying of migration and lets them run automagically from the host app
initializer :append_migrations do |app|
  next if app.root.to_s.start_with?(root.to_s) # only run when called from other apps
  app.config.paths['db/migrate'].concat(config.paths['db/migrate'].expanded)
end
```